# Ho do I undo those steps in Linux

Tags: linux, mono, echo, apt, tee

Hello I've tried to install mono by tutorial on mono project website not knowing that I already have mono in my repository on rpi

I would like to know how to undo steps I did

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
echo "deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Thank you for any kind of help

Answer (score 1):

to remove the key

```
sudo apt-key del 3FA7E0328081BFF6A14DA29AA6A19B38D3D831EF
```

to remove the source open `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mono-xamarin.list`
and remove this line `deb http://download.mono-project.com/repo/debian wheezy main`
then rerun

```
sudo apt-get update
```